# How do i run C# code using Python in Linux

Tags: python, c#, python-2.7, mono

I am trying to run C# code from python in Ubuntu.

```
# Dynamically add IQFeed.CSharpApiClient DLL
import os

assembly_path =  r"/IQFeed.CSharpApiClient.dll"
print(os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', None))
import sys
print(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(assembly_path)
print(sys.path)

# Reference IQFeed.CSharpApiClient DLL
import clr

clr.AddReference("IQFeed.CSharpApiClient")

from IQFeed.CSharpApiClient import IQFeedLauncher
from iqf_creds import dtn_login, dtn_password, dtn_product_id

# Step 1 - Run IQConnect launcher
IQFeedLauncher.Start(dtn_login, dtn_password, dtn_product_id)
```

I followed and installed, mono-complete, pythonnet etc.

```
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-3 Mon Apr 27 19:25:46 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

pythonnet version is pythonnet==2.5.2

I am trying to get iqfeed market data, following https://github.com/mathpaquette/IQFeed.CSharpApiClient/blob/master/docs/USING-WITH-PYTHON.md

I am quite new to C# area, but it looks like i am getting the following error.

```
None
/home/nara/PycharmProjects/Algorithm2/IQFeed
['/home/nara/PycharmProjects/Algorithm2/IQFeed', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/nara/PycharmProjects/Algorithm2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/nara/PycharmProjects/Algorithm2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/clr_loader-0.1.6-py3.8.egg', '/home/nara/PycharmProjects/Algorithm2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cffi-1.14.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/IQFeed.CSharpApiClient.dll']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iqf_get_data.py", line 20, in <module>
    IQFeedLauncher.Start(dtn_login, dtn_password, dtn_product_id)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00129] in <a85c1a570f9a4f9f9c3d2cfa5504e34f>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00038] in <a85c1a570f9a4f9f9c3d2cfa5504e34f>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0001e] in <a85c1a570f9a4f9f9c3d2cfa5504e34f>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName, System.String arguments) [0x00007] in <a85c1a570f9a4f9f9c3d2cfa5504e34f>:0 
  at IQFeed.CSharpApiClient.IQFeedLauncher.Start (System.String login, System.String password, System.String productId, System.String productVersion, System.Int32 connectionTimeoutMs, System.Int32 retry) [0x00115] in <703036e983534afca652edbe7b984272>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0007c] in <12b418a7818c4ca0893feeaaf67f1e7f>:0
```

Wondering if anyone had success running C# apps in ubuntu. I am not using wine, but directly using mono. Any assistance would be helpful. Importantly, this code appear to work ok under windows, so i wonder if it has to do with pythonnet + mono